# Powershell - problem Array,OU and Combobox

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with a powershell script. I need to retrieve the OU list of a domain with specific credentials so I use a job and the -credential command to be able to run my script. I recover the ORs without worries in an array.

However when I read the table to test in write-host, no problem all the OUs are there and well sorted.

But when I try to add them to a combobox I only have the number of lines, and then instead of having the OR I have "(Collection)" the same number of times that I have had number displayed.

Any idea ?

thank you

[image]

```
#region Generated Form Objects
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$comboBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#region Generated Form Code
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 261
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 284
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.Text = "Primal Form"

$comboBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = $True
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 24
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 70
$comboBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 21
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 248
$comboBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$comboBox1.TabIndex = 0

$form1.Controls.Add($comboBox1)

#endregion Generated Form Code

    $login = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
    $password = "XXXXX"
    $pass = Convertto-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$login,$pass)


$GetProcessJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {

    $Searcher=[adsisearcher]""
    $Searcher.searchRoot = [ADSI]"XXXXXXX"
    $Searcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)"
    $allObjects = $Searcher.FindAll()
    
    New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList
    $arrlist = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    foreach ($obj in $allObjects) { 
            $arrlist.add($Obj.Properties.Item("Name"))
           }

    $arrlist = $arrlist | Sort-Object
    
    return $arrlist
  
} -Credential $Cred

    Wait-Job $GetProcessJob

    $GetProcessResult = Receive-Job -Job $GetProcessJob
    $GetProcessResult 
    foreach($line in $GetProcessResult)
        {
            
            $comboBox1.Items.add($line) 
               }
#$array
#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateFormenter code here
```

Comment: Change `$arrlist.add($Obj.Properties.Item("Name"))` to `[void]$arrlist.add($Obj.Properties.Item("Name")[0])`

Comment: My hero <3 thank you ! But why ?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `$Obj.Properties.Item("Name")` returns a `[ResultPropertyValueCollection]` with only one item. To get just the raw string value, you'll want to add `$Obj.Properties.Item("Name")[0]` to the list instead.

The next problem you'll encounter is that the combobox will fill with a bunch of integers before it lists the actual OU names. This is because the call to `$arrList.Add(...)` returns the index at which the new item was inserted, so the final output from the job will be integers 0 through N-1, followed by N OU names.

To fix both issues, change the loop inside the job like this:

```
foreach ($obj in $allObjects) { 
    $arrlist.add($Obj.Properties.Item("Name")[0]) |Out-Null
}
```

Additionally, you can remove this functionally redundant statement (which currently just creates an empty list and throws it away immediately):

```
New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you